# build path including a jar file with multiple error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

There is a jar file that is our dependency. In order to include it into our project, I have tried:

1) using pom. On the left, I could see it under Maven dependencies, and the packages in this jar. But when I open the class, it says: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

2) using eclipse, build path, external jar, again I can see it in the reference library, and the class is invalid LOC header (bad signature)

3) lower the jdk I use, from jdk8 to jdk6, does not help.

4) maven update, maven clean, clean project, none helps.

5) untar its source.jar and zip it, add this source.zip in build path external archive, in reference library, under source.zip all the folders/packages are gone except one empty folder.

I have checked the source.zip, most java files seem to be ok. And I also checked the class jar file, all the class files seem to be OK too. Very difficult to understand what caused these, and how to resolve this dependency problem.

Comment: seems like a corrupted jar file. Remove the jar file from _.m2 repository_, recompile the dependencies if you have the source code and try again.

Comment: going forward, put some stack trace of the errors and the pom file you've used if there are still issues.

Comment: @SamuelKok it seems to be an IDE problem. The same pom and same project run on IDEA works fine.